# ListItem is not showing text from the "title" property in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using [ListItem](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/lists/) from react native elements in a FlatList, the code is

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={commonStyles.container}>
        <List>
          <FlatList
            data={this.props.questions}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <ListItem
                roundAvatar
                title={'nicola'}
              />
            )}
          />
        </List>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

The issue is that text ( 'nicola' ) is not rendered

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Edit 03/04/2022

The new syntax is available here :
https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/components/listitem

I know this is quite late, but I had encountered the same issue.

```
const list = [
{
    name: 'Account',
    icon: 'av-timer'
},
{
    name: 'Category',
    icon: 'flight-takeoff'
},
{
    name: 'About',
    icon: 'av-timer'
}]

... // some code here

   <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    {
        list.map((item, i) => (
            <ListItem
                key={i}
                title={item.name}
                leftIcon={{ name: item.icon }}
            />
         ))
    }
   </View>
```

When I used the above code, only icons were shown, but the issue was resolved when I removed alignItems prop.

Comment: Had exactly the same issue, and solved by removing alignItems prop. Thanks a lot, you just saved my day!

Comment: I had `alignItems: 'center'` on a superview which triggered the same behavior. Removing `alignItems` worked.

Comment: wow, that's crazy. Thanks! I wonder what causes this to happen because of a styling prop.

Comment: Be aware, the new syntax is quiet different now

Answer (score 3):

Remove

> alignItems: "center"

in View

Comment: This should be the Awnser

Answer (score 0):

Don't use FlatList inside List, use ListItem, and provide key to it

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={commonStyles.container}>
        <List>
          {
             this.props.questions.map((l, i) => (
               <ListItem
                 roundAvatar
                 key={i} // <-- new property
                 title={'nicola'}
               />
             ))
           }
         </List>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still doesn't show anything. I'll use a flatlist with a <Text> inside

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are adding a FlatList RN component as a child in every list. You are actually making a list of lists.

Try this:

```
    render() {
        return (
          <View style={commonStyles.container}>
            <List>
{
    this.props.questions.map((item, i) => (
      <ListItem
             roundAvatar
            title={'nicola'}
           />
    ))
  }

            </List>
          </View>
        );
      }
```

Edit: After seeing the answer about the keys, I am not sure if that would be the problem. RN uses it to determine if every row is different, but you should be seeing only one row if that were the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sfjm.png) way

```
import { ListItem, Avatar } from '@rneui/themed'

const list = [
  {
    name: 'Amy Farha',
    avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice President'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris Jackson',
    avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
  }
]

<View>
  {
    list.map((l, i) => (
      <ListItem key={i} bottomDivider>
        <Avatar source={{uri: l.avatar_url}} />
        <ListItem.Content>
          <ListItem.Title>{l.name}</ListItem.Title>
          <ListItem.Subtitle>{l.subtitle}</ListItem.Subtitle>
        </ListItem.Content>
      </ListItem>
    ))
  }
</View>
```

[image]